# illegal string offset 'Servername' in C:wamp\www\report\index.php on line 234

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

i am trying to execute the query below using wampserver in php.

```
$query = "SELECT Servername,IPAddress,LiveStatus,
                 Location,BranchType,Entity 
          FROM t_applicationstatus 
          Where Entity='BAGI'";


$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

it is giving me the above error.

Comment: can you post the table structure of `t_applicationstatus`

Comment: Where do you fetch the row? Please show some more code.

Answer (score 1):

It does not like Servername that may be a declared value somewhere else.
 
That error is usually associated with an array
 
Put the accent marks (`) around the field name to distinguish it as a column.